# NUXT (production, extractCSS: true) does not remove inline styles of some Vue packages

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

The styles of some of the plugins (sweet alert, owl carousel) are duplicated inline and in the link tags, despite the inclusion of extractCSS.

My nuxt.config.js

```
css: [
    '~/assets/sass/style.sass',
    '~/assets/css/style.css',
  ],
build: {
    vendor: ['axios', '~plugins/vue-swal', '~plugins/vue-owl-carousel'],
    extractCSS: true
  },
```

I need to put all of the styles into separate files

Comment: Remove those css files from your plugins.

Comment: styles are integrated into js files